# Initializing an Array of ElementRefs in Angular

Tags: angular

I’m refactoring a video chat app that I’m building using Angular 12, and I’ve run into what is probably a simple question that I’m not having much luck finding an answer to.

When I send the video and audio output to my display components via an ElementRef, I’ve been using a static name for the variables in the video service, something like…

```
video.service.ts

localParticipant: elementRef
remoteParticipant1: elementRef
remoteParticipant2: elementRef
```

…then linking them to their display components in the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook.

```
all-remote-participants.component.ts

@ViewChild('remoteParticipant1', { static: false }) remoteParticipant1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('remoteParticipant2’, { static: false }) remoteParticipant2: ElementRef;

  constructor(private videoService: VideoService) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.videoService.remoteParticipant1 = this.remoteParticipant1
  this.videoService.remoteParticipant2 = this.remoteParticipant2
}
```

This works fine when you have a fixed number of participants, but since you can have “n” number of remote participants, what I wanted to do was create an array of ElementRefs named something like…

```
video.service.ts

remoteParticipant: elementRef[]
```

...so I can do...

```
remoteParticipant[0]
remoteParticipant[1]
```

…which would allow me to have a factory of display components and give me more flexibility.

```
remote-participant.component.ts

@Input() participantId: number
@ViewChild('remoteParticipant', { static: false }) remoteParticipant: ElementRef;

  constructor(private videoService: VideoService) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.videoService.remoteParticipant[this.participantId] = this.remoteParticipant
}
```

What I can’t figure out is what to put in the parentheses to push elementRefs onto the array. I’ll list my results below of what I’ve tried.

The variable is initialized as:

```
remoteParticipant: ElementRef[];
```

I’ve tried:

This creates the ElementRefs but they're empty, so you can't address nativeElement:

```
remoteParticipant.push({} as ElementRef)
```

Builds an array of nulls, which doesn't work:

```
remoteParticipant.push(null)
```

All of the rest are empty arrays:

```
remoteParticipant.push([])
remoteParticipant.push({})
remoteParticipant.push()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just a thing for this. You should use decorator `@ViewChildren`.

It returns `QueryList` and you can access multiple elements inside it. The `@ViewChildren` decorator supports directive or component type as parameter, or the name of a template variable. Read more about it on https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren.

You can also safely remove `{ static: false }` since it's a default.

Adjust this answer for your needs, but it should look like this ->

`@ViewChildren('remoteParticipants') remoteParticipant1: QueryList<ElementRef>;`

Then you can access to length of this array of `ElementRef`, first element, last one...

Comment: Thank you for pointing me down this path. I wasn't aware of ViewChildren or ContentChildren, so this proved very useful!

Comment: It says I don't have enough reputation to vote yet, "but my vote has been counted," so hopefully it will appear once I have enough reputation points. I really appreciate it!